# Want more Clojure way to brute force string match

Tags: string, clojure, match

I've implementing a brute force string matching algorithm in Clojure. It works as it should, but what I'm looking for is how to make this code "cleaner," and more readable. Note that I also have to have the algorithm print out how it's doing the character comparisons. I don't know about all the conventions to pay attention to, and I'd really like some tips on how to write Clojure better.

What it does: It takes a piece of text, and for each of it's indexes (since the text is of a type String), match it with the input string. If there's a match, we compare the second character to the next index of the text. It's a lot to explain in English, but if you run the program, it prints out what it's doing.

The code:

```
(defn underscores [n]
  (apply str (repeat n "_")))

(defn brute_force_string_match
  "Receives text as string type as its first argument,
  string in second argument, brute force matches the
  string to the text. Assumes text is longer than string."

  [text
   string]
  ;; for loop
  ;; i is 1 less than the amount of No matches you will get
  (loop [i 0
         j_and_matches [0 0]]
    ;;outer loop stops when i > n -m
    (if (and
             (<= i (- (count text) (count string)))
             (not= (j_and_matches 0) (count string)))
      ;; the "while loop"
      (do
        (println "")
        (print "\nPos = " i "\n"text"\n"
                   (str (underscores i) string))
        (recur
           (inc i)
           (loop [j 0
                  print_pos i
                  undscore_amt 0
                  matches (j_and_matches 1)]
             (if (and
                 (< j (count string))
                 (= (.charAt string j) (.charAt text (+ i j))))
               (do
                 (print "\n" (str (str (underscores print_pos)) "^   Match! "))
                 (recur (inc j)
                        (inc print_pos)
                        (inc undscore_amt)
                        (inc matches)))
               (do
                 (if (not= j (count string))
                   (print "\n" (str (str (underscores print_pos)) "^   No Match ")))
                 [j matches])))))

      (if (= (j_and_matches 0) (count string))
        (do (println "\n Pattern found at position " (dec i))
            (println "The number of comparisons: " (+ (j_and_matches 1) (dec i)))
            (dec i))
        -1))))
```

Comment: I don't have a full reworking, but one small thing: `(print "\n" (str (str (underscores print_pos)) "^   Match! "))` is better expressed as `(print (str "\n" (underscores print_pos) "^   Match! "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, `j` has no place in your outer loop, which has `i` go through the possible start points for a match. `j` is the local index into `string` while testing it against the `text` starting from `i`.

I'd write it something like this:

```
(defn brute_force_string_match [text string]
  (let [last-start (- (count text) (count string))]
    (loop [i 0, matches []]
      (if (> i last-start)
        matches
        (let [match?
              (loop [j 0]
                (or (= j (count string))
                    (and (= (.charAt string j) (.charAt text (+ i j)))
                         (recur (inc j)))))]
          (recur (inc i) (if match? (conj matches i) matches)))))))
```

Apart from the superfluous `j` in your outer loop, I don't know that yours is significantly different from this.

As a matter of style,

- I've bound the complex inner `loop` expression to local `match?`. This keeps the final
  line clear.
- I've used `and` and `or` to simplify the conditionals in that expression.
- I've pushed down the conditional `(if match? ... )` into an argument of the
  outer recur.

*Note*

You can use `get` instead of `.charAt` to access characters of strings.